# Is there a special behavior of parse_ini_file() I should be aware of?

Tags: php, arrays, ini

I have a quite big `INI` file *(around 100kb and over 2000 lines)* which I am trying to parse with PHP: `$ini_array = parse_ini_file("config.ini");`

But the function throw a warning: `PHP Warning: syntax error, unexpected '(' in config.ini on line 1334 in ...`

Looking at line `1334` won't show any syntax error. Then I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976757/debugging-a-php-ini-syntax-error) :

> Short answer:
>
> Don't trust the line numbers, look for a syntax error in the lines before the line mentioned in the error.

I am confident that there is no error in the file because its used in production by an other tool wrote in Pascal.

So,

- How I could check the file manually for errors ?
- And if no syntax error exist in the file, is there a behavior of `parse_ini_file()` I should be aware of ?

Comment: *"Is there a tool which can help me to check the syntax of my ini file ?"* - Any good code editor with pair matching is what you "need".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found in the PHP manual :

> Characters ?{}|&~![()^" must not be used anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value.

From `PHP 5.3.0` we can set a third parameter `scanner_mode`. So
calling `parse_ini_file()` with `INI_SCANNER_RAW` as third parameter did the trick - the function do not evaluate values.

By default the function use the `INI_SCANNER_NORMAL` mode and evaluate values.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/function.parse-ini-string.php

Answer (score 1):

You could try a "manual" approch, dichotomy search.

1. Remove lines after the line 1333.
2. Then remove lines before by (large) blocks until you have no error.
3. Add lines by smaller blocks until you have error again.

You will find the error.